# Segue not being called

Tags: swift, segue

I am trying to bypass a sign-in view if the user has already signed in once. I have run tests and know I'm getting to the right code. But the segue is never executed.

```
    //bypass the sign in screen if user has already signed in

    let signInCheck = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("editProfile")

    if (signInCheck! .isEqual(1)) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedIn2", sender: nil)
    } else {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(1, forKey: "editProfile")
    }
```

Any help would e appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more code (the function and where you are calling it, or verify you checked that its being called) and some outputs you are receiving (like print signInCheck after you assign it).